# Using SQL Profiler to get the name of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, sql-server-profiler

I have a database (SQL server 2000) with almost a thousand of stored procedures and I want to know which stored procedure is called after a button is clicked. 
I try to use SQL Profiler (version 8.0) to capture the name of the stored procedure, but it seems it's not possible to get the name directly from SQL Profiler.

A [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx) says I can get the stored procedure name by running:

```
Select name from sysobjects where id = <ObjectID>
```

I tried but the id matched nothing.
How can I get the name of the stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/

Comment: Thanks, but most solutions can not be applied to SQL server 2000.

Comment: Before you run SQL Server Profiler, limit traces by adding filters as much as possible. For example, provide database name or database id as you can find at http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/prevent-sql-injection-using-parameterized-query.aspx Add other criterias...

Comment: @YHTsai Where is the button clicked? What application? What type of "button"?

Answer (score 0):

This small query can give you a preview (the first 8000 characters) of your database T-SQL code (Procedures, Functions, Triggers, etc):

```
select o.id
    ,case 
        when parent_obj = 0
            then ''
            else '[' + Object_Name(parent_obj) + '].'
     end + o.Name as Name
    ,c.text
    ,xType as Type
from syscomments c
join sysobjects o on (o.id = c.id)
where ColId = 1
    and Category = 0
order by o.xType
    ,name
    ,c.Colid
```